# Serial port sysbuffer outSize exceeds the value specified through fconfigure

Tags: serial-port, tcl, buffer, buffer-overflow, serial-communication

If I open a serial port:

```
% set serial_com6 [open com6 r+]
file1a21465b4a0
```

and set set its `outSize` and `inSize` through

```
% fconfigure $serial_com6 -sysbuffer {512 512}
```

so far things seem ok:

```
% fconfigure $serial_com6 -sysbuffer
512 512
```

except I can put about `4096` bytes without overflowing:

```
% for {set i 0} {$i < 4096} {incr i} {put $serial_com6 { }}
% fconfigure $serial_com6 -queue
0 4096
```

This doesn't make scene. I would appreciate if you could help me know how I can query / set the maximum input / output buffer size of a serial port.

**P.S.1.** I forgot to say my OS is Windows 10 and I'm using Tcl 8.5 inside Scilab / ScosLab

**P.S.2.** i might just have found the solution. from [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/serial/versions/2.0/source):

```
%fconfigure $serial_com6 -buffersize
4096
```

gives me the max buffer size and i can also set it like:

```
% fconfigure $serial_com6 -buffersize 512
% fconfigure $serial_com6 -buffersize
512
```

So apparently Windows doesn't use the `sysbuffer` or they are pointing to two different things which I do not understand.

Comment: Assuming of course that your OS actually respects the request to set those particular buffers to those sizes. It may have its own minima and maxima…

Comment: @DonalFellows so you are telling me the Os doesn't care that I set those values? fine. how can I measure the max values then?

Answer (score 1):

While Tcl can request that settings change on a serial port, it is actually up to the OS to change them: it's free to constrain values as it sees fit (or throw errors). You'll need to see [the Windows documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setupcomm) for what that value actually can be set to (it's not one of the portable settings).

The `-buffersize` option controls the size of Tcl's own output buffer in the generic layer of the channel system, and not anything at the OS level; when in `-buffering full` mode, it tries to accumulate (at least) that many bytes before writing them out. You probably don't want to use full buffering for a serial port, given how slow it is. You might want to use a non-blocking serial port (`-blocking 0`) and run an event loop: then Tcl will stream your output out to the serial port as fast as it can behind the scenes (or you can use a writable `fileevent` to take more control).